# Plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension interrupted in IOS

Tags: ios, linkedin-api, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm using UIActivityViewController to share text and link to Linkedin.
I got the errors:

```
plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension interrupted
plugin com.linkedin.LinkedIn.ShareExtension invalidated
```

I installed Linkedin app on my ios device. How can I fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem.

Comment: have the same problem. Dialog view appears and in after that immediately disappears with these 2 errors in log.

Comment: are you able to find any solution for this.?